# Bloquear ciertas horas en un timepicker

Tags: bootstrap, timepicker

Quisiera saber como bloquear ciertas horas en un `timepicker`, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#HORA').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 30, 
        showMeridian: false, 
        modalBackdrop: false,
        template: 'dropdown',
        showInputs: false,
    });
</script>

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><label for="hora">Hora :</label></span>
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">  
        <input type="text" name="HORA" id="HORA" placeholder="HH:MM" required readonly title="HH:MM" maxlength="5" value="10:00" class="form-control">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito realizar: si me muestra las 24 horas del día, que me bloquee por ejemplo de las 10:30 a las 13:30 para que no puedan seleccionar dicha hora, he buscado información, pero no encuentro el método que permita realizar esto.

Comment: Que librería de timepicker estás usando?

Comment: La libreria que estoy usando es js/bootstrap-timepicker.js y js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js